# How to acquire pictures of a particular patent?

Tags: patent-applications, wo2012007964a2

I am interested in acquiring the accompanying pictures in reference to the patent: [WO2012007964A2](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2012007964A2)

Answer (score 1):

From the link you provided to the Google Patents page, click on the "Espacenet" link, then click on the "EP Register" link, and select "All Documents". The document you are looking for (the international application that contains the Figures) is the following one:

`19.01.2012     International publication of the A2 Pamphlet    Search / examination    31 pages`

Comment: The link to Patentscope from the Google Patents page would also work. On Patentscope, go to either the Drawings tab or the Documents tab. On the Documents tab, you can download the publication of the application, including the specification and the drawings ("Initial Publication without ISR (A2 03/2012)").